# How to get the class of the genereric parameter of a Interface from the interface

Tags: java, generics

I have this Interface:

```
public interface Test<T> {
    default Class<?> getT() {
        return T.getClass(); < --error
    }
}
```

next i have a class that implements it:

```
static class ItemService implements Test<Item>{
}
```

And i want to get the 'Item' class **from the 'ItemService' class**

```
static ItemService service = new ItemService();

private static void k() {
    System.out.println(service.getT());
}
```

Now one way to do it is this:

```
public interface Test<T> {

    default Class<?> getT() {
        return Type.type;
    }

    class Type {

        public static Class<?> type;

    }

}
```

Service:

```
static class ItemService implements Test<Item> {

    public ItemService() {
        Type.type = Item.class;
    }

}
```

And it works fine but there is a problem,
When another class implement the interface:

```
static class OrderService implements Test<Order> {

    public OrderService() {
        Type.type = Order.class;
    }
}
```

And i try:

```
static ItemService service = new ItemService();
static OrderService orderservice = new OrderService();

private static void k() {

    System.out.println(service.getT());

}
```

**I get the Order class and not the Item class**

How can i make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes inside interfaces are static, You can remove the default from the function and every class will need to implement this. example:

```
public interface Test<T> {
    public Class<T> getT();
}

static class ItemService implements Test<Item> {
    public Class<Item> getT() {return Item.class;}
}

static class OrderService implements Test<Order>{
    public Class<Order> getT() {return Order.class;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could be an abstract class.

```
public interface Test<T> {
    public Class<T> getT();
}

abstract class AbstractTest<T> implements Test<T> {
    private final Class<T> type;
    AbstractItemService(Class<T> type) { this.type = type }
    public Class<T> getT() {return type;}
}

class ItemService extends AbstractTest<Item> {
  ItemService() { super(Item.class); }
  // implement other things
}

class OrderService extends AbstractTest<Order>{
  OrderService() { super(Order.class); }
  // implement other things
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option, if your implementation has an instance of T.

```
interface Test<T>{
    T getT();
    default Class<?> getClassOfT(){
        return getT().getClass();
    }
}
```